# Объясните в какой папке из "android" "core" "desktop" нужно выполнять андроид проект

Tags: java, android

Вопрос заключается в том, что в каждой из этих трех папок лежит папка src в которой есть java исполняемый файл, и я не понимаю, где нужно работать, и зачем нужны эти разные папки.

Comment: Папки нужны, потому что так захотел автор проекта. Но скорее всего в `core` лежат общие классы, в `desktop` - десктопная версия приложения, а в `android` - кодовая база приложения под Android.